# Magento 2.1.4: Order Summary Modal on Checkout Breakpoint

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, order-summary

I'm trying to get the Order Summary slide-in Modal (`id="opc-sidebar"`) on the Checkout Page stay in for landscape tablet (up to 1024px).

At the moment it changes to be in the right hand column at 768px.
I can't find the file where this is set. It seems like quite a stupid question, however when I was doing the same for the off canvas menu it was quite simple with there being the `_toggleMobileMode`, `_toggleDesktopMode` and the `mediaCheck` in the menu.js.

I've taken a look at the devDocs, and feel like I've looked in every file in the module-checkout folder but I've had no luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!